# How can we use @Tree('closure-table') in NestJs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I want use `@Tree('closure-table')` so I have the below method and entity:

```
 public async create(createCategoryDto: CreateCategoryDto) {
    try {
      const manager = getManager();
      const category = await this.categoryRepository.create(createCategoryDto);
      return await manager.save(category);
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

And entity:

```
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Tree,
  TreeChildren,
  TreeParent,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
@Tree('closure-table')
export class Category {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @TreeChildren()
  children: Category[];

  @TreeParent()
  parent: Category;
}
```

but this one can't create the tree, Is there anyone that knows the problem?

**Note:** Examples of typeorm document are very simple.

Answer (score 1):

this one worked for me:

```
public async create(createCategoryDto: CreateCategoryDto) {
    try {
      if (!createCategoryDto.parentId) {
        const category = await this.categoryRepository.create(
          createCategoryDto,
        );
        return await this.categoryRepository.save(category);
      }

      const parent = await this.categoryRepository.findOne(
        createCategoryDto.parentId,
      );
      const child = await this.categoryRepository.create(createCategoryDto);
      child.parent = parent;
      return await this.categoryRepository.save(child);
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```